# Unassign and reassign public ip address in VNIC, OCI Python SDK

Tags: python, oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

From OCI Python, i want to be able to unassign a public ipv4 address in a VNIC, and then reassign a new ephemeral one.

Answer (score -1):

Please check the API provided to update the IP in the OCI Python SDK here:

```
update_private_ip(private_ip_id, update_private_ip_details, **kwargs)
```

https://oracle-cloud-infrastructure-python-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/core/client/oci.core.VirtualNetworkClient.html#oci.core.VirtualNetworkClient.update_private_ip